# Difference between PromQL "by" and "without" unclear

Tags: prometheus, calculation, promql

I have a question about calculating response times with Prometheus summary metrics.

I created a summary metric that does not only contain the service name but also the complete path and the http-method.

Now I try to calculate the average response time for the complete service.
I read the article about "rate then sum" and either I do not understand how the calculation is done or the calculation is IMHO not correct.

As far as I read this should be the correct way to calculate the response time per second:

```
sum by(service_id) (
    rate(request_duration_sum{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
    /
    rate(request_duration_count{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
)
```

What I understand here is create the "duration per second" (rate sum / rate count) value for each subset and then creates the sum per service_id.

This looks absolutely wrong for me - but I think it does not work in the way I understand it.

Another way to get an equal looking result is this:

```
sum without (path,host) (
    rate(request_duration_sum{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
    /
    rate(request_duration_count{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
)
```

- But what is the difference?
- What is really happening here?
- And why do I honestly only get measurable values if I use "max" instead of "sum"?

If I would ignore everything I read I would try it in the following way:

```
rate(sum by(service_id) request_duration_sum{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
/
rate(sum by(service_id) request_duration_count{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
```

But this will not work at all... (instant vector vs range vector and so on...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All of these examples are aggregating incorrectly, as you're averaging an average. You want:

```
  sum without (path,host) (
    rate(request_duration_sum{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
  )
/
  sum without (path,host) (
    rate(request_duration_count{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
  )
```

Which will return the average latency per `status_code` plus any other remaining labels.

Comment: I think this is right - because you wrote it. But I would like to understand what is really done by the given queries. What lecture do I have to study? Online-Courses, Bible...? ;-)

Comment: Try the [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/).

Answer (score 9):

- The `by` modifier groups [aggregate function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions) results by labels enumerated inside `by(...)`.
- The `without` modifier groups [aggregate function](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions) results by all the labels  except those enumerated inside `without(...)`.

For example, suppose `process_resident_memory_bytes` metric exists with `job`, `instance` and `datacenter` labels:

```
process_resident_memory_bytes{job="job1",instance="host1",datacenter="dc1"} N1
process_resident_memory_bytes{job="job1",instance="host2",datacenter="dc1"} N2
process_resident_memory_bytes{job="job1",instance="host1",datacenter="dc2"} N3
process_resident_memory_bytes{job="job2",instance="host1",datacenter="dc1"} N4
```

Then `sum(process_resident_memory_bytes) by (datacenter)` would return summary per-`datacenter` memory usage, while `sum(process_resident_memory_bytes) without (instance)` would return summary per-`job` per-`datacenter` memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Using Prometheus metrics in Grafana, the `without` keyword did not work for me (at least as I expected it to). I got satisfying results with `by`:

```
  sum by (status_code)(
    rate(request_duration_sum{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
  )
/
  sum by (status_code)(
    rate(request_duration_sum{status_code=~"2.*"}[5m])
  )
```