# Is there a syntax of Prometheus request that avoid repeating of the same labels in the selectors?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I use Prometheus+Grafana and write formulas like:

```
(
  (
    sum(
      rate(
        http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{name="$avalon_apdex_service", kubernetes_namespace="$ns", uri!~"$uri", status!~"5..", le="1.0"}[5m]
      )
    )+
    sum(
      rate(
        http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{name="$avaon_apdex_service", kubernetes_namespace="$ns", uri!~"$uri", status!~"5..", le="4.0"}[5m]
      )
    )
  )/2
)
/
sum(
  rate(
    http_server_requests_seconds_count{name="$avalon_apdex_service", kubernetes_namespace="$ns", uri!~"$uri"}[5m]
  )
)
```

Frankly speaking, I'm tired to repeat the same (mostly the same) labels in the selectors.

It would be great if I can write something like:

```
    with{name="$avalon_apdex_service", kubernetes_namespace="$ns", uri!~"$uri"} (
    ((
    sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status!~"5..",le="1.0"}[5m]))+
    sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{status!~"5..",le="4.0"}[5m]))
    )/2)
    /sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[5m]))
    )
```

I read the Prometheus manual and didn't realize is there a syntax that will make my formulas less wordy?

Comment: Don't have the time to write an answer now, but take a look at this example, it might give you a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51065271/11344502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus doesn't provide functionality to write repeated label filters only once. If you need this functionality, then take a look at [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. Its' [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) provides e.g. `WITH templates` feature, which resolves exactly this issue. For example, the query above can be written in the following way in order to specify repeated label filters only once:

```
WITH (
  cf = {name="$avalon_apdex_service", kubernetes_namespace="$ns", uri!~"$uri"},
  cfNo5xx = cf{status!~"5.."},
)
(
  (
    sum(
      rate(
        http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{cfNo5xx, le="1.0"}[5m]
      )
    )+
    sum(
      rate(
        http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{cfNo5xx, le="4.0"}[5m]
      )
    )
  )/2
)
/
sum(
  rate(
    http_server_requests_seconds_count{cf}[5m]
  )
)
```

Try this query at [WITH playground](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/expand-with-exprs?query=WITH+%28%0D%0A++cf+%3D+%7Bname%3D%22%24avalon_apdex_service%22%2C+kubernetes_namespace%3D%22%24ns%22%2C+uri%21%7E%22%24uri%22%7D%2C%0D%0A++cfNo5xx+%3D+cf%7Bstatus%21%7E%225..%22%7D%2C%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%28%0D%0A++%28%0D%0A++++sum%28%0D%0A++++++rate%28%0D%0A++++++++http_server_requests_seconds_bucket%7BcfNo5xx%2C+le%3D%221.0%22%7D%5B5m%5D%0D%0A++++++%29%0D%0A++++%29%2B%0D%0A++++sum%28%0D%0A++++++rate%28%0D%0A++++++++http_server_requests_seconds_bucket%7BcfNo5xx%2C+le%3D%224.0%22%7D%5B5m%5D%0D%0A++++++%29%0D%0A++++%29%0D%0A++%29%2F2%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%2F%0D%0Asum%28%0D%0A++rate%28%0D%0A++++http_server_requests_seconds_count%7Bcf%7D%5B5m%5D%0D%0A++%29%0D%0A%29).

The query can be simplified further though:

```
WITH (
  cf = {name="$avalon_apdex_service", kubernetes_namespace="$ns", uri!~"$uri"},
  cfNo5xx = cf{status!~"5.."},
  sumrate(m) = sum(rate(m[5m])),
)
(
  (
    sumrate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{cfNo5xx, le="1.0"})
    +
    sumrate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{cfNo5xx, le="4.0"})
  )/2
)
/
sumrate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{cf})
```

Try experimenting with this query [here](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/expand-with-exprs?query=WITH+%28%0D%0A++cf+%3D+%7Bname%3D%22%24avalon_apdex_service%22%2C+kubernetes_namespace%3D%22%24ns%22%2C+uri%21%7E%22%24uri%22%7D%2C%0D%0A++cfNo5xx+%3D+cf%7Bstatus%21%7E%225..%22%7D%2C%0D%0A++sumrate%28m%29+%3D+sum%28rate%28m%5B5m%5D%29%29%2C%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%28%0D%0A++%28%0D%0A++++sumrate%28http_server_requests_seconds_bucket%7BcfNo5xx%2C+le%3D%221.0%22%7D%29%0D%0A++++%2B%0D%0A++++sumrate%28http_server_requests_seconds_bucket%7BcfNo5xx%2C+le%3D%224.0%22%7D%29%0D%0A++%29%2F2%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%2F%0D%0Asumrate%28http_server_requests_seconds_count%7Bcf%7D%29).